# Visualize the attached diagram with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

[image]

Is there a way in Tikz to draw a diagram like this?

Comment: I think the answer is probably: *Yes*.

Comment: Use [`tikz-cd`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-cd).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Ok so i've looked up the doc of tikz-cd but there is no "no arrow" that equals these entail symbols

Answer (score 4):

To give you a start. The shift of `-6pt` is explained as twice the `inner sep` plus the `outer sep`, all of which have default values of `2pt`. Solutions using `\makebox` to achieve the same screw up the bounding box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[every arrow/.append style={%
    double distance=0.4ex,cyan,-{Bar[width=1.6ex]}}]
  & \varphi_3\arrow[dl]\arrow[d]\\
  \varphi_2 \arrow[ddr,shift right=1ex] & 
    |[label={[xshift=-6pt]right:\equiv\varphi_6}]|\varphi_1 \arrow[d]\\
  &\varphi_4\arrow[d]\\
  &\varphi_6\\
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not know if the red marks are on purpose in your screen shot. If they are, it is easy to add them as long as it is clear what they are (check marks, brackets, ???).

Comment: Damn thanks mate. Could you explain the change of arrows so in the future i know how to change them?

Comment: @RackCloud All I did was to add `every arrow/.append style={double distance=0.4ex,cyan,-{Bar[width=1.6ex]}}` to control their appearance. `double distance=<distance>` means that they are drawn as double lines separated by `<distance>`, cyan is a color and the `Bar` arrow head can be looked up in section  **16.5 Reference: Arrow Tips** of the pgfmanual v3.1.4.

Comment: \begin{tikzcd}
& \varphi_7 \equiv\varphi_8 \arrow[d]
\end{tikzcd}
now i want to add a diagram that 7 equals 8 tried to just delete the other points but it didn't work am new to tikz and latex

Comment: Got it \begin{tikzcd}
& \varphi_7\equiv\varphi_8
\end{tikzcd}

Comment: @RackCloud If you say `\arrow[d]` in a given cell, then you need to make sure that a cell below that cell exists. So e.g. `\begin{tikzcd} 
& \varphi_7 \equiv\varphi_8 \arrow[d] \\
& {}
\end{tikzcd}` will work.

Comment: So what if i want to include that in the other tikzcd ? so varphi_3 with varphi_8 and varphi_7 with varphi_5

Comment: @RackCloud I am sorry, I do not understand what you mean by "what if i want to include that in the other tikzcd". The arguably cleanest way would be to ask a new question in which you precisely show what you are trying to do (and to accept this answer if it solved your original problem).